# Accessing local resources from a content script

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way i can access local resources inside a script?
I need to access `data.url('layout.html')`, `data.url('icon.png')` and `data.url('style.css')` inside the contentScript handler.

```js
exports.main = function() {
  require("widget").Widget({
    onClick: function() {
      tabs.activeTab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: [ data.url('jquery.js')],
        contentScript:
          "setTimeout(function(){ alert('asd');}, 100);",
        });
    } 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using `cssUrl = data.url('alert.css')`. In main.js i set this up, and in the script running client-side add a script having `href=cssUrl`.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. If you have lots of stuff in /data and you need all of those urls, you could always create some bootstrap code that creates a big map of urls and posts them all into the content script.

Comment: same question from a chrome extension? yes: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Answer (score 0):

Use contentScriptOptions to pass it to the content script, like this:

```
//main.js
contentScriptFile: [ data.url('jquery.js')],
contentScriptOptions: {
   cssUrl: data.url('alert.css')
}

// jquery.js
console.log(self.options.cssUrl)
```